# Restrict parameter ranks in optim

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to optimize a function using `optim(par = init)`, with the restriction that the parameter vector is always in increasing order? For example, `c(1,2,8)` would be allowed but `c(1,2,0)` would not be permitted?

Comment: That are linear constraints, which can be handled in `constrOptim()`. See also CRAN TaskView https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: @jogo Great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `constrOptim()` which can handle linear constraints:

```
constrOptim(theta=c(..), f=.., grad=NULL, 
   ui=matrix(c(-1,1,0, 0,-1,1), 2, byrow=TRUE), ci=c(0, 0))
```

Comment: Are there dangers in using the Nelder-Mead implied by `grad=NULL` rather than using `BFGS` in `optim` as would be possible for Otto_K's answer? It seems that I can't use BFGS without calculating a gradient using `constrOptim`, but I can under pure `optim`.

Comment: I suppose the danger is less than in the answer of Otto_K (manipulating the objective function to discontinuity). BFGS is a method for constructing a proxy for the Hessian from gradients step by step. A gradient can be approximated per finite differences.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this condition in the optimization function:

If your function to maximize is:

```
fn<-function(x,y,z){

  -x^2-(1+y)^2-(z-y)^2

}
```

You need to change it to:

```
fn<-function(x,y,z){
   if(x<y&&y<z){
      return(-x^2-(1+y)^2-(z-y)^2)
   }
   else{
      return(-Inf)
    }

}
```

Now you can optimize this function.

Comment: This is no longer continuous and differentiable. That may cause problems.

Comment: This is always the case with restriction optimization. However Monte Carlo optimization can help avoiding this problem:
 
optim(par = init,method="SANN")

Comment: That is a silly statement. An LP is considered continuous and differentiable. The objective and each constraint is continuous and differentiable.